# Is there a reason why event.key doesn't work halfway through my code?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I've been working on a project in PyGame. To test the currency system out, I've decided to increment the money you have when a key is pressed. I've tried moving the if statement out of the game loop. Here's my code:

```
gameRun = True
while gameRun:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.key == pygame.K_p:
            print("This Should Work")
            currency.balance.amount += 1
            pygame.display.update()
```

I have other several other lines of code but I believe that there is something wrong about these lines. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a reason why event.key doesn't work halfway through my code?

I guess you have more than 1 event loop, respectively call to [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) are there in your code.
Note `pygame.event.get()` removes the events from the queue. If you have more than 1 event loop, then just one random loop will get the events, all the other loops go empty-handed. That causes that you'll miss events.

Get the list of events once in the main application loop and use same list of events in multiple event loops. e.g:

```py
gameRun = True
while gameRun:
    events = pygame.event.get()

    for event in events:
        if event.key == pygame.K_p:
            print("This Should Work")
            currency.balance.amount += 1
            pygame.display.update()

    # [...]

    foo(event)

    # [...]

    for event in events:
        # [...]
```

```py
def foo(events):
    for event in events:
        # [...]
```